# Is there a way to cc: someone on a bug/work item in Microsoft Team Foundation Server?

Tags: tfs

I am using Team Foundation Server with Visual Studio 2010 and with the Team Foundation Server Power Tools.

The alerts explorer in the power tools allows you to set up tfs to send you email alerts when someone changes your work items, or assigns you a work item. These were two different alerts i had to configure. You can also right click an existing work item and have yourself emailed an alert when anything changes. This took a while for us to figure out.

In other companies/projects i have worked, the usual bug systems is bugzilla and a very common thing to do is to CC other people/lists you know would be interested on a bug/work item. That way they will get an email, and will be emailed about any further changes to the work item/bug. This is a very common method of communicating information to people or groups.

Although with the TFS Power Tools i can right click a work item and have myself get alerts (effectively I can CC: myself), is there a way to CC: other people?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's a great question.  When you create an alert using the Alerts Editor, you can put multiple e-mail addresses for people to be notified.  They will be on the "To:" line instead of the "CC:" line.  Would that work out for you?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is asking about 2010, but in TFS 2012, you can enter a value of @username in the Comments field to trigger an email to go to someone else along with your WorkItem update, even if they aren't subscribed (I believe).

Comment: This is for Team Server, not Team Foundation Server. Although the @mention control works for pull requests and other things, but not for work items. This might see the light in TFS 2016. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2016/03/31/vs2015-update-2-and-tfs-2015-update-have-shipped/